# How to deal with different sized objects in a pathfinding situation (A*, A-star)

Tags: path-finding, a-star

I'm working on a game that uses A-star (A*) for path finding but I've come to a point where by I have some objects that are larger than a single grid square.

I'm running on a grid of 16*16px. wall segments are 16*16 and so make a single square impassable. Some of my baddies are 32*32 and so they need to check that a gap is at least 2 grid square wide in order to be able to pass throguh it.

I can't simply make the grid 32*32 as the design requires thin walls (at 16px) and there are a couple of smaller baddies that only take up a single 16*16 square.

How do I implement this mutli-resolution environment?
Is A-star still the correct tool to use?

Answer (score 1):

For a relatively simple solution, I would stick to the same A* algorithm as for 16x16 sized objects but with a slightly different way to evaluate if a square is walkable or not.

- A 16x16 sized object can walk on a square if that square is walkable.
- A 32x32 sized object can walk on a square if that square and its' neighbors are all walkable.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work when a gap is 2 squares tall. Both squares of the gap have non-walkable neighbours so report as non-walkable. It might be better to say a tile is walkable for 32-sized objects if the square below it, to its right, and below-and-right are also walkable.